# HybridAuth CakePHP3.X,how to save user after successful login?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, hybridauth

I have read the description [over](https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth),

Once a user is authenticated through the provider the authenticator gets the user profile from the identity provider and using that tries to find the corresponding user record in your app's users table. If no user is found and **registrationCallback** option is specified the specified method from the User model is called. You can use the callback to save user record to database.

But where to define/declare **registrationCallback**

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to register if not exist then this code will execute :

```
if (!empty($this->_config['registrationCallback'])) {
            $return = call_user_func_array(
                [
                    TableRegistry::get($userModel),
                    $this->_config['registrationCallback']
                ],
                [$provider, $providerProfile]
            );
            if ($return) {
                $user = $this->_fetchUserFromDb($conditions);
                if ($user) {
                    return $user;
                }
            }
```

You need to define the registration function in config ( in __construct) and regarding **call_user_func_array** read this link  - https://php.net/call-user-func-array

Answer (score 0):

To Store user in database after login

1>defines the function in UsersTabel.php

```
public function registration($provider, $profile) {
        $user = $this->newEntity([
                                     'username'     => $profile->displayName,
                                     'provider'        => $provider,
                                     'provider_uid' => $profile->identifier
                                 ]);
        if(!$this->save($user))
        {
            Log::write(LOG_ERR, 'Failed to create new user record');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

2>Replace the function of file vendor ▸ admad ▸ cakephp-hybridauth ▸ src ▸ Auth▸ HybridAuthAuthenticate.php

```
public function __construct(ComponentRegistry $registry, $config)
    {
        $this->config([
            'fields' => [
                'provider' => 'provider',
                'provider_uid' => 'provider_uid',
                'openid_identifier' => 'openid_identifier'
            ],
            'hauth_return_to' => null,
            'registrationCallback'=>'registration'
        ]);

        parent::__construct($registry, $config);
    }
```